# How can I change rowsPerPage in MaterialReactTable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I used MaterialReactTable and I want to show just 5 items in each pagination. I set muiTablePaginationProps but I still have 10 items.How can I do?

```
 <MaterialReactTable
  columns={columns}
  data={data.data}
  muiTablePaginationProps={{
    rowsPerPageOptions: [5],
    rowsPerPage: 5,
  }}

/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `material-react-table` documentation ([Pagination Feature Guide](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination#manage-pagination-state)) you should remove `rowsPerPage` from `muiTablePaginationProps` and add `initialState` property to MaterialReactTable component as follows:

```js
<MaterialReactTable
  initialState={{ pagination: { pageSize: 5,pageIndex: 0 } }}
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  muiTablePaginationProps={{
    rowsPerPageOptions: [5],
  }}
/>;
```

You can see image preview [at here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0e0A.png)

Comment: Thank u for your help. I thought pageSize is for another thing